# Creating a calculated column in Spotfire for Cumulative / running totals based on a criteria

Tags: spotfire

I need to show cumulative total of a particular column in a cross table and I am not able to create a formula for this. So, I thought of creating a cumulative totals column in underlying data based on few conditions like region (local, foreign), Source (Internal, external) etc. but I am not able to create this. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you post screenshots of your original data table (with some dummy data) and the final output (what do you want to achieve)? You can create the final output table in excel. This would help us in providing a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the formula below where `[Value]` is the column you are aggregating.

```
Sum([Value]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.Rows])) as [CustomFormula]
```

Here is what it would look like in a cross table:

[image: Cross Table]